# 2D Real-Time Ray-tracing

Tags: glsl, shaders

I've written a 2D ray-tracer in GLSL ES for GameMaker for dynamic lighting. I've also written a blog post on how it works... though it is out-dated. I am looking to have JUST my shaders reviewed to see if there is anything that can be done to simplify or improve performance. Here is a [download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c8s4QCsBDUJjpMfbDKrixg4fyCuNWLjt) link to the full working example as well as a link to the [blog post](https://forum.yoyogames.com/index.php?threads/quick-ray-traced-qrt-lighting-tutorial.60842/).

Here is a visual example of how it works:
[image]

The first shader takes in a small texture--small enough to just store the results of the rays traced as colors--and traces out the length of each ray of the light until a collision is made on the world map (collision texture/surface). The resulting ray length is converted into an RG color and sent to gl_FragColor. This creates an index lookup table for the second shader to reconstruct the actual light from the ray table. You can see in the reference image how each ray maps to the lookup table texture onto the light.

The second shader takes the ray lookup table and reconstructs the light using the pre-traced rays. Each pixel will check 1 ray and at worst case 2 rays. In the event that a pixel fails the first ray check it looks up the next closest ray and checks against that just in case.

[image]

An important bit of info here:

```
// The maximum radius allowed for the light.
MAXRADIUS = 64.0;
// The pow2 size of the ray-map texture calc'd as: exp2(ceil(0.5 * log2(2 * PI * MAXRADIUS)));
in_RayTexSize = 32.0;
// The pow2 size of the light texture calc'd as: exp2(ceil(log2(2 * MAXRADIUS)));
in_LightTexSize = 128.;
```

You can see in the shaders below and the example I've commented out the uniform inputs in the shaders and hand-inputted them myself for testing.

```
/*
    This shader does the ray-tracing and stores the resulting length of each ray as a 2-byte float in the RG(red-green) color of gl_FragColor.
*/
uniform sampler2D in_WorldMap;
uniform vec3 in_Light;
uniform vec2 in_World;
varying vec2 in_Coord;
//uniform float in_RayTexSize;
const float in_RayTexSize = 32.0;
const float PI2 = 2. * 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
const float MAXRADIUS = 64.0;

void main() {
    // Gets the current pixel position in X,Y coordinates (instead of UV).
    vec2 Coord = floor(in_Coord * in_RayTexSize), xyRay = vec2(0.),
        // Gets the ray index in the ray lookup texture and calcs out the number total rays to check against (2 * pi * r).
        RayMap = vec2((Coord.y * in_RayTexSize) + Coord.x, (PI2 * in_Light.z));

    // Checks if the ray index we're writting to is within bounds.
    if (RayMap.x <= RayMap.y) {
        // Gets the ray direction around the light center.
        float Theta = (PI2 * (RayMap.x / RayMap.y));
        vec2 Step = vec2(cos(Theta), -sin(Theta));

        // Traces the ray to max radius (since GLSL requires const loops).
        for(float rad = 0., d = 0.; d < MAXRADIUS; d++) {
            // Performs ray checks only within light bounds.
            if (rad >= in_Light.z) break;
                // Steps across the light ray.
                xyRay = floor((Step * d) + 0.5);
                // Fancy trick to cancel ray checking by moving out of light bounds.
                rad = d + (in_Light.z * texture2D(in_WorldMap, (in_Light.xy + xyRay) * in_World).a);
        }

        // Converts the length of the ray to a 2-byte float color (RG).
        float rayLength = length(xyRay) / in_Light.z;
        xyRay = vec2(floor(rayLength * 255.0) / 255.0, fract(rayLength * 255.0));
    }

    // Passes the ray info into the ray texture lookup table.
    // This will be black (no ray, if out of bounds).
    gl_FragColor = vec4(xyRay, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

```
uniform sampler2D in_WorldMap, in_LightMap;
uniform vec3 in_Light, in_Color;
uniform vec2 in_World;
varying vec2 in_Coord;
//uniform float in_RayTexSize, in_LightTexSize;
const float in_RayTexSize = 32.0, in_LightTexSize = 128.;
const vec2 in_TexCenter = vec2((in_LightTexSize * 0.5) + 0.5);
const float PI2 = 2. * 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;

// Takes in the ray-index and does a lookup in the ray texture lookup table.
// This will convert the RG ray length to a float for the actual length.
float getRayFromIndex(float index) {
    vec2 RayPos = vec2(mod(index, in_RayTexSize), index / in_RayTexSize) * (1./in_RayTexSize),
        TexRay = texture2D(in_LightMap, RayPos).rg;
    return clamp(TexRay.r + (TexRay.g / 255.0), 0.0, 1.0) * in_Light.z;
}

// Gets the next closest index to the input.
float getNearIndex(float index) {
    return 1. + (-2. * (1. - floor(fract(index) + 0.5)));
}

void main() {
    // Gets the current pixel position in X,Y coordinates (instead of UV).
    vec2 Coord = in_Coord * in_LightTexSize;
    // Gets the distance of the pixel to the light center.
    float Distance = distance(Coord, in_TexCenter);
    vec4 Color = vec4(0.);

    // Only light up this pixel if it's within light bounds.
    if (Distance < in_Light.z-1.) {
        // Gets the relative position/distance around the light.
        vec2 Delta = Coord - in_TexCenter;
        // Constructs and pre-computes our light's tonemap.
        float ToneMap = 1. - (Distance/in_Light.z), RayCount = (PI2 * in_Light.z),
            // Gets the ray index relevant to the current pixel.
            RayIndex = RayCount * fract(atan(-Delta.y, Delta.x)/PI2),
            // Gets the next closest ray index relevant to the current pixel.
            RayIndexNear = RayIndex + getNearIndex(RayIndex),
            // Calculates the pixel's luminescence.
            xyRay = sign(getRayFromIndex(RayIndex) - Distance) * ToneMap;

        // If the ray check fails, check the next closest ray for validation.
        if (xyRay <= 0.)
            if ((RayIndexNear-RayCount) * RayIndexNear <= 0.)
                xyRay = sign(getRayFromIndex(RayIndexNear) - Distance) * ToneMap;

        // Do not light up any pixel that has a collision under it.
        xyRay *= (1. - texture2D(in_WorldMap, (in_Light.xy + Delta) * in_World).a);
        Color = vec4(in_Color, 1.) * xyRay;
    }

    // Output the final constructed light pixel.
    gl_FragColor = Color;
}
```

Comment: How come you don't use Github instead of google drive?

Comment: I have it under a private repo. I just haven't had the tine to set up a proper public repo with documentation, etc.

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Comment: @Mast the deed is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I am going to give myself and [@XorDev on Twitter](https://twitter.com/XorDev) kudos on this one. We worked together to optimize and simplify the process of ray-tracing the lights and removed a bunch of redundant code. Here are the final versions:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///Shd_RayTracer (Final)
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
uniform sampler2D in_WorldMap;
uniform vec3 in_Light;
uniform vec2 in_World;
uniform float in_RayTexSize;
varying vec2 in_Coord;
const float MAXRADIUS = 65535., TAU = 6.2831853071795864769252867665590;

void main() {
    vec2 Coord = floor(in_Coord * in_RayTexSize),
        xyRay = vec2((Coord.y * in_RayTexSize) + Coord.x, TAU * in_Light.z);
    float Theta = TAU * (xyRay.x / xyRay.y);
    vec2 Delta = vec2(cos(Theta), -sin(Theta));

    float Validated = step(xyRay.x,xyRay.y);
    for(float d = 0.; d < MAXRADIUS * Validated; d++) {
        if (in_Light.z < d + in_Light.z * texture2D(in_WorldMap, (in_Light.xy + xyRay) * in_World).a) break;
        xyRay = floor(Delta * d + 0.5);
    }

    float rayLength = length(xyRay) / in_Light.z;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec2(floor(rayLength * 255.0) / 255.0, fract(rayLength * 255.0)), 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///Shd_LightSampler (Final)
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
uniform sampler2D in_WorldMap, in_LightMap;
uniform vec3 in_Light, in_Color;
uniform vec2 in_World, in_LightCenter, in_TexCenter;
uniform float in_RayTexSize, in_LightTexSize;
varying vec2 in_Coord;
const float TAU = 6.2831853071795864769252867665590;

void main() {
    vec2 Coord = in_Coord * in_LightTexSize,
        Delta = Coord - in_TexCenter;
    float RayCount = TAU * in_Light.z,
        RayIndex = floor((RayCount * fract(atan(-Delta.y, Delta.x)/TAU)) + 0.5);
    vec2 RayPos = vec2(mod(RayIndex, in_RayTexSize), RayIndex / in_RayTexSize) * (1./in_RayTexSize),
        TexRay = texture2D(in_LightMap, RayPos).rg;
    float Distance = distance(Coord, in_TexCenter),
        RayLength = clamp(TexRay.r + (TexRay.g / 255.0), 0.0, 1.0) * in_Light.z,
        RayVisible = sign(RayLength - Distance) * (1. - texture2D(in_WorldMap, (in_Light.xy + Delta) * in_World).a),
        ToneMap = 1. - (Distance/in_Light.z);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(in_Color * ToneMap, RayVisible);
}
```

**SHADER: Shd_RayTracer**

The first major hurdle was just eliminating IF-Statements. I didn't actually know that if-statements and the code they encapsulate still continue to run despite the fact that typically IF-statements keep that from happening. Not in shaders, IF-statements and the code they encapsulate all still get evaluated regardless....

So instead what @XorDev mentioned was that I should be using the `step(a,b)` as a comparative validation statement to multiply by the condition for my `for loop`. This multiplies out and cancels the for-loop by setting the condition to 0 loops in the event that a pixel is out of range of the set of rays to be indexed. Fancy.

Next I realized that specifically for GameMaker when running GLSL ES shaders that the size of the for-loop does not affect run-time or compile time. So I don't think GameMaker is particularly unrolling the for loop here when compiling the shader. So I set the for loop to the maximum radius of what this shader will be processing on, `2^16-1` radius or a `2*(2^16-1)` diameter light. Plenty for games IMO. The reason for this restriction is to reduce the actual floating point conversion to RG components when rendering to the texture for a total of 2 bytes instead of 3 or 4 for efficiency purposes.

***CANCELING OUT DISTANCE IN LOOP***
As another user mentioned, I do not need to cancel out the distance in order to break away from the loop. This is false and actually highly necessary. The reason for the trickery here is to prematurely exit the for-loop in the event that we've hit a collision and don't want to proceed tracing out the full length of the ray.

**SHADER: Shd_LightSampler**

Again the same idea was used here as well, just simply eliminate the if-statements. The shader still runs the same, but more efficiently, even if I am not evaluating out each pixel via an IF-statement. Branching is slow. The reason here that the shader still runs the same is that I actually multiply out the color to black if the pixel is out of range regardless, so pixels outside the light radius still end up blank.

Finally one of the bigger hurdles was eliminating the secondary ray check. Originally I had designed the shader to check the 2 closest rays to the pixel being rendered in the event that the first ray failed to validate the pixel. Essentially this was unnecessary and all I did was `floor()` the desired ray index so as to get the correct ray appropriate for the pixel where as before it was hit or miss depending upon rounding errors.

This all allowed for several other small optimizations such as not using several multiplication maths to calculate out the `ToneMap` based on whatever IF-condition.

**TL:DR**

IF-statements are bad, GPUs love floating point operations and I can prematurely exit loop iterations. Fantastic, I saw about a 6x improvement on speed roughly, though I'm not doing rigorous highly skilled testing. All I know is that now I can render more lights at higher radius (roughly 600 lights at a 512px radius on a 1080 Ti) and in the order of thousands of lights with smaller and smaller radius, eventually hitting a bandwidth cap I believe on the part of either GameMaker or my GPU, no idea.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you're doing a ray march when you could be using the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

---

If the maximum distance of your ray is 64, why do you need two components (RG) to store it? Consider other formats like R8, R16, floating point texture formats, or `floatBitsToInt`.

---

Multiple declarations in a statement is hard to read, especially when they're not aligned.

---

You can vary in texel (XY) space instead of texture(UV) space, and skip some multiplications. You can also use something like gl_FragCoord which may be easier to manage.

---

breaking from the inside of a loop is fine, you don't need tricks like cancelling out the distance.

---

Prefer `texelFetch` instead of `texture2D` when appropriate -- i.e. when you don't need filtering. `texture2D` implies lod calculations may be relevant and can adversely affect branching.

---

Finally, I don't believe this will perform better than rasterizing 2D data into a set  of 1D viewports in a way similar to shadow mapping. The rasterization approach has many huge advantages like being able to batch-cull an enormous amount of data.

Comment: The max radius is adjustable. Hence the RG component.

Comment: Bresenham would be more accurate, but would it be more efficient...?

Comment: I haven't personally benchmarked it but I would bet that it's more efficient. It should yield the minimal number of necessary points to test. Compare to a diagonal ray march -- it will do sqrt(dx^2+dy^2) iterations, where bressenham will do dx(==dy).

Comment: Final question, at the second shader at comment/section "// If the ray check fails," is there a way I can avoid this second ray check? The second ray is validation in the event that the first ray doesn't collide with the light pixel, but the second might. Right now it's necessary via this implementation, any way around this?

Comment: With the current algorithm I'm not sure -- if I understand it right, the rays will get more sparse the farther a pixels from a light, and the rays in the second shader will be potentially further and further away? If your texture is too small, I would expect there to be slight holes where there's no light near the edges of lines.

Comment: Instead, what if you did: 1. for each light's bounding box, collect all intersecting lines. 2. for each pixel in the bounding box, perform ray-line intersection tests on every line with every pixel position going to the light. This has very different performance characteristics -- it will run very fast if there is minimal geometry, but crushingly slow if there's a ton of lines all stacked on each other. Note that the collection process can be run on the GPU, but since it's outputting variable (but bounded) data, it's much more complex.

Comment: Yeah that's a bad idea. Because of the particular kind of work being done here, shaders are perfect for this. I am actually receiving performance in orders of hundreds to thousands of lights depending upon light radius size. The concept already works, just working towards cleanup and optimization. See also: https://twitter.com/FatalSleep/status/1213395686663737344?s=20

Comment: Not to mention that the flexibility here to enable pixel-level detail + ray traced lighting is enormously powerful. So I don't see any benefit moving towards slower, more complicated shadow casting and geometry calculations.